# converting a string to stringified JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm getting a string which looks like following

```
"{option:{name:angshu,title:guha}}"
```

Now I have to make a valid JSON string from this. Is there any smart way to convert that. I tried with string handelling but that takes a lot of conditions still being case specific. Even i tried with eval() that doesn't work also.

Comment: Did you mean JSON object? If yes, then use JSON.parse("{option:{name:angshu,title:guha}}")

Comment: _Is there any smart way to convert that_ -> Fix the server code to submit a valid JSON string.

Comment: @Andreas Gotta agree. I've encountered converting browser JSON objects to a flat string to be submitted to server but never I see servers returning JSON objects as flat strings!

Comment: Is this JSON object coming from server side as an AJAX response? If it is then convert it to a JSON object and send it, like we have some_object.to_json in Rails.

Comment: I was actually crawling a bulk number of jsfiddle links to separate HTML, CSS and JS file using phantomjs. In that case I found the JSON data from the JS code is coming in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex will do the trick for the provided example string:

```
/:([^{},]+)/g
```

[Regex101 analysis of it](https://regex101.com/r/lZ4fS1/1):

```
: matches the character : literally  
1st Capturing group ([^{},]+)  
   [^{,}]+ match a single character not present in the list below  
       Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible,   giving back as needed [greedy]  
       {}, a single character in the list {}, literally  
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

Basically, it looks for all characters following a `:` that aren't `{},`. those "words" are saved in the 1st capturing group, which allows `.replace` to re-use them with `$1`.

You can use the regex like this:

```js
var raw = "{option:{name:angshu,title:guha}}",
    regex = /:([^{,}]+)/g,
    replacement = ':"$1"';

var jsonString = raw.replace(regex, replacement);

alert(jsonString);
```

Comment: Superb dude.. That saves my day. :)

Comment: You're welcome. However, keep in mind that this _will_ break when your string contains one of these `{},` characters. The regex is far from bomb-proof.

Answer (score -3):

try this if you are looking for JSON object

```
 string inputString = '{option:{name:angshu,title:guha}}';
 var obj = JSON.parse(inputString);
```

Comment: The JSON itself is not valid, I don't think you can parse it.

Comment: Why is this getting upvoted? This won't work because the string is invalid JSON, which is _the reason_ the OP asked this question in the first place.